# Expand makefiles

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I've got a huge project that uses many makefiles, via `include`. At one point, a macro is set (properly) but at another point, when I expect to be able to use it, it is no longer defined.

Basically, I run a local makefile for my project, it `include`s a global makefile for the framework I'm using (openFrameworks). This one `include`s other makesfiles depending on platform, which addons my project depends on, etc.

I'd love to have a command similar to `cpp` but for makefiles, so that I can get a view of what things would look like with all `include`s and macros expanded.

I've tried using `remake -X` to debug this, but it seems like it will always run everything until it hits the first target. The first target appears long after the things I'm worried about.

Comment: Try `make -p` and `make -d`.

Comment: The output of `make -p` should be the resultant `makefile` with all the `include` lines resolved. It may not show you repeats of the macro definitions.  I do have makefile expansion technology (as 170-odd lines of Perl script originally written in 1999 and needing more orthodox handling of lexical filehandles) that can read the include lines and include the relevant files.  To contact me for it, see my profile.

Comment: `make -p` will not show you everywhere a variable is defined.  But it will show you (at least with current versions of GNU make) the _last_ place the variable was defined (filename and line number).  If you're trying to learn who's overriding your variable value that might be sufficient.

Comment: @Zack Have you even looked at the `make -d` output? It is not even nearly what I'm looking for. @Jonathan-Leffler Curiously, none of the macros defined by the makefiles seem present in `make -p` or `make -p Debug`.

Comment: Are you undefining any variables in your makefiles? Could it be that you erroneously undefine that one?

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Though I never got the problem solved, I've worked around it and sadly don't have the time to revisit it. openFrameworks has some 2.5k loc in makefiles, which call and/or include each other depending on platforms, plugins, etc. It's quite a mess.